# Hangfire: launch queued job, for tests

Tags: hangfire

I have part of code:

```
var jobId = jobClient.Enqueue<IComposerJob>(c => c.Compose(email.Id));
```

inside Compose I Enqueue another job:

```
var jobId = BackgroundJob.Enqueue<ISenderJob>(s => s.Send(emailId));
```

So, for test that I have Mock to enqueue:

```
jobclient.Verify(x => x.Create( It.Is<Job>(job => job.Method.Name == "Compose" && job.Args[0].ToString() == composed.Id.ToString()), It.IsAny<EnqueuedState>()));
```

and here I want launch Compose job to check creating internal Send job, that's a problem

Thanx in advance)

Comment: what is exactly your problem ? BackgroundJob not being a mock ? This does not seem breaking for your test